# very odd server crashing / network issue

Tags: networking, ssh

#### TLDR

I have 3 linux boxes. They had been running without issue for 9, 6 and 3 hours roughly. They all stopped responding to ssh and pings at the same time.

Restarting / checking network didn't solve anything.

Restarted box C, got `a start job is running for raise network interfaces` but still no pings

Restarted box B - started getting pings on A and C

How can box B stop box A and C responding. The rest of my network was fine.

Update:

It also happened the next morning. All 3 boxes went down at the same time. I turned off box B and the other 2 became responsive again.

I also tried running a physical network cable to the machines and that didn't help either.

#### Full Story

I have been having a lot of issues with reliability on my linux boxes that I am trying to setup. I have 2 machines, A, B and C.

These boxes are mining rigs and I am trying to narrow down where the hardware issue is on one of them that keeps making it restart / become unresponsive.

However I now think that this might be a network issue instead. The symptoms are that they become completely unresponsive over ssh - I can't even exit my client and have to hard close it.

I had assumed that this was because the machine had crashed (all 3 machines are headless so I can't look on the screen to see what is going on).

Tonight I had been running the machines all day to ensure that the current cut down hardware configuration was stable. The machines had been running for 9 hours, 6 hours and 3 hours - or something like that.

I got the unresponsive ssh issue at exactly the same time on all 3 machines. I could not ping the machines either.

At this point I assumed a network issue and that if I restarted the network the pings would come back.

I checked the network (Google WiFi) and all looked good but I restarted it anyway and got nothing.

I then restarted box C. I watched it booting up and it got stuck on

`a start job is running for raise network interfaces`

and waited 5 minutes before completing the boot, and I still couldn't ping it.

I then restarted box B.

At the point I started getting pings from box A and C again.....!!!

What on earth is going on here. How can box B wipe out all network communications on box A and C!

I am totally flummoxed!

The boxes are all Ubuntu Server latest version (16 something)

Comment: *They all stopped responding to ssh and pings at the same time* pretty much tells the whole story. Something happened in the network and that has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok but why would restarting one of them start the other 2 working